# Dialog Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

index.cshtml code

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#finestra").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <p>
        JQuery Dialog Test
    </p>
    <div id="finestra" title="Test">
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting a `0x800a01b6` - JavaScript runtime error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' error`. I have added a jquery 1.11.4 reference. I checked other similiar questions but could not find a problem it is causing.

Comment: It sounds like the jQueryUI library is not loading correctly. Have you checked that the path is right? Also, you appear to be using jQuery 1.10.2, not 1.11.4

Comment: jquery-ui.js is 1.11.4 verion...

Comment: When I start debugging, I can confirm that it is calling "var dialog = $.widget( "ui.dialog", {" in jquery-ui.js and is returning a constructor. After it reaches at  $("#finestra").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); ,jquery-1.10.2.js starts executing

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        //"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"));
        }
```

I commented `"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"` so the code didnot refer the older jquery and it worked.